# Using asyncio for Non-async Functions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Suppose there is a library that makes various database queries:

```
import time

def queryFoo():
    time.sleep(4)
    return "foo"

def queryBar():
    time.sleep(4)
    return "bar"
```

I want to execute those 2 queries concurrently without having to add `async` to the method signature or adding a decorator.  These functions should not depend on asyncio at all.

**What is the best way to utilize those non-async functions within `asyncio`?**

I am looking for something of the form:

```
#I need an 'asyncWrapper'

results = asyncio.gather(asyncWrapper(queryFoo()), asyncWrapper(queryBar()))
```

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If some function is blocking and not async by nature, only proper way to run it inside `asyncio` event loop is to run it inside thread using [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_in_executor):

```
# Our example blocking functions
import time


def queryFoo():
    time.sleep(3)
    return 'foo'


def queryBar():
    time.sleep(3)
    return 'bar'


# Run them using asyncio
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


_executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(10)


async def in_thread(func):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return await loop.run_in_executor(_executor, func)


async def main():
    results = await asyncio.gather(
        in_thread(queryFoo), 
        in_thread(queryBar),
    )

    print(results)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    finally:
        loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
        loop.close()
```

It does job.

If you however want to avoid using threads only way to do it - is to rewrite `queryFoo`/`queryBar` to be async by nature.

Comment: Coming from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55645527/python-asyncio-runtimeeror-this-eventloop-is-already-running/55651314?noredirect=1#comment105248777_55651314), the example you showed above will still need async function for `run_in_executor()`, while I want to make sure the async function converted to sync such that I don't have nested async calls that have nested event loops. One of the solutions I can think of is to spawn new event loop for the inner async calls and block until its result got returned, and continue to next outer loops. Will that work?

Comment: @EmersonXu *1)* if you want to cast some async function to sync, you just have to do `loop.run_until_complete(asyncfunc())` inside sync funtions. But once you did it, you've done with async world at all: from now on all your outer code is sync. *2)* If you want to cast some sync function to async, use `await loop.run_in_executor(_executor, syncfunc)` inside other async functions. *3)* If you want to do something else, I'm afraid it's hard to me to understand it without reproducible code example.

Comment: If `queryFoo` has input (keyword) arguments, I can add a line in `in_thread` to do `func = partial(func, *args, **kwargs)`, or is there a better way? (and `partial` comes from `from functools import partial`).

Comment: @BertCoerver `partial` - is a proper way to handle such situation.

Answer (score 15):

I presume you are after concurrency and hopefully do not insist on using `asyncio` module itself in which case this little example could be helpful:

```
import asyncio
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def queryFoo():
    time.sleep(2)
    return "FOO"

def queryBar():
    time.sleep(4)
    return "BAR"

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    foo = executor.submit(queryFoo)
    bar = executor.submit(queryBar)
    results = [foo.result(), bar.result()]

print(results)
```

It runs both `queryFoo()` and `queryBar()` in parallel and collects their results in a list in order in which they've been mentioned in an assignment to `results`.

Comment: Looks like he updated the question to say he does need it to be an "asyncio wrapper".