# Python - How to - Big Query asynchronous tasks

Tags: python, async-await, google-bigquery

This may be a dummy question but I cannot seem to be able to run python google-clood-bigquery asynchronously.

My goal is to run multiple queries concurrently and wait for all to finish in an `asyncio.wait()` query gatherer. I'm using `asyncio.create_tast()` to launch the queries.
The problem is that each query waits for the precedent one to complete before starting.

Here is my query function (quite simple):

```
async def exec_query(self, query, **kwargs) -> bigquery.table.RowIterator:
  job = self.api.query(query, **kwargs)
  return job.result()
```

Since I cannot await `job.result()` should I await something else?

Comment: Is it mandatory to use `asyncio`? Bigquery's python api has no support for async yeild so better option probably would be to execute the queries on background at some ThreadPool executor.

Comment: I'm just starting with python, but would it be possible to wrap the query as an async call with your method?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are working inside of a `coroutine` and want to run different queries without blocking the `event_loop` then you can use the `run_in_executor` function which basically runs your queries in background threads without blocking the loop. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51051980/1002277) a good example of how to use that.

Make sure though that that's exactly what you need; jobs created to run queries in the Python API are already asynchronous and they only block when you call `job.result()`. This means that you don't need to use `asyncio` unless you are inside of a coroutine.

Here's a quick possible example of retrieving results as soon as the jobs are finished:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import google.cloud.bigquery as bq


client = bq.Client.from_service_account_json('path/to/key.json')
query1 = 'SELECT 1'
query2 = 'SELECT 2'

threads = []
results = []

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(5)

for job in [client.query(query1), client.query(query2)]:
    threads.append(executor.submit(job.result))

# Here you can run any code you like. The interpreter is free

for future in as_completed(threads):
    results.append(list(future.result()))
```

`results` will be:

```
[[Row((2,), {'f0_': 0})], [Row((1,), {'f0_': 0})]]
```

Answer (score 6):

just to share a different solution:

```
import numpy as np
from time import sleep


query1 = """
SELECT
  language.name,
  average(language.bytes)
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.languages` 
, UNNEST(language) AS language
GROUP BY language.name"""
query2 = 'SELECT 2'


def dummy_callback(future):
    global jobs_done
    jobs_done[future.job_id] = True


jobs = [bq.query(query1), bq.query(query2)]
jobs_done = {job.job_id: False for job in jobs}
[job.add_done_callback(dummy_callback) for job in jobs]

# blocking loop to wait for jobs to finish
while not (np.all(list(jobs_done.values()))):
    print('waiting for jobs to finish ... sleeping for 1s')
    sleep(1)

print('all jobs done, do your stuff')
```

Rather than using `as_completed` I prefer to use the built-in async functionality from the bigquery jobs themselves. This also makes it possible for me to decompose the datapipeline into separate Cloud Functions, without having to keep the main `ThreadPoolExecutor` live for the duration of the whole pipeline. Incidentally, this was the reason why I was looking into this: my pipelines are longer than the max timeout of 9 minutes for Cloud Functions (or even 15 minutes for Cloud Run).

Downside is I need to keep track of all the `job_id`s across the various functions, but that is relatively easy to solve when configuring the pipeline by specifying inputs and outputs such that they form a directed acyclic graph.

Comment: I'm trying to copy this with about 200 queries each of which takes about 10 seconds so I have
`for q in queries:
      job = bq.query(query[q])
      jobs_done[job.job_id] = False
      job.add_callback(dummycallback)
print("Now wait")`
I am not seeing any significant speedup. Seems like the slow part is launching the query itself.

Comment: That could well be the case, note that BQ startup times are of order several seconds. So if you have ma up small queries, you won't see much improvement.

Answer (score 2):

I used @dkapitan 's answer to provide an async wrapper:

```py
    async def async_bigquery(client, query):
        done = False
        def callback(future):
            nonlocal done
            done = True
        job = client.query(query)
        job.add_done_callback(callback)
        while not done:
            await asyncio.sleep(.1)
        return job
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact I found a way to wrap my query in an asyinc call quite easily thanks to the `asyncio.create_task()` function.
I just needed to wrap the `job.result()` in a coroutine; here is the implementation. It does run asynchronously now.

```
class BQApi(object):                                                                                                 
    def __init__(self):                                                                                              
        self.api = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(BQ_CONFIG["credentials"])                               

    async def exec_query(self, query, **kwargs) -> bigquery.table.RowIterator:                                       
        job = self.api.query(query, **kwargs)                                                                        
        task = asyncio.create_task(self.coroutine_job(job))                                                          
        return await task                                                                                            

    @staticmethod                                                                                                    
    async def coroutine_job(job):                                                                                    
        return job.result()
```

Comment: Am struggling with the same question @Antoine Dussarps. Have posted an issue on google-cloud-python, referencing this thread. https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/8726

Comment: I don't think that's doing what you want. `create_task` schedules some async work and lets you `await` it. This is so you can start several tasks in parallel but it does not convert blocking calls into `async` calls. When `coroutine_job` is called it will still block the event loop. What you want here is to run this in a thread via [to_thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-in-threads).

Comment: This is weird. This snippet does nothing but wraps a sync function into async function. The event loop will be blocked during the execution of the query.