# Bigquery, save clusters of clustered table to cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-python

I have a bigquery table that's [clustered](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-clustered-tables) by several columns, let's call them `client_id` and `attribute_id`.

What I'd like is to submit one job or command that [exports that table data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_stored_in) to cloud storage, but saves each *cluster* (so each combination of `client_id` and `attribute_id`) to its own object. So the final uri's might be something like this:

`gs://my_bucket/{client_id}/{attribute_id}/object.avro`

I know I could pull this off by iterating all the possible combinations of `client_id` and `attribute_id` and using a [client library](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.extract_table) to query the relevant data into a bigquery temp table, and then export that data to correctly named object, and I could do so [asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53065340/python-how-to-big-query-asynchronous-tasks).

*But....* I imagine all the clustered data is already stored in a format somewhat like what I'm describing, and I'd love to avoid the unnecessary cost and headache of writing the script to do it myself.

Is there a way to accomplish this already without requesting a new feature to be added?

Thanks!

Comment: feature requests can be submitted at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659

Comment: I've updated my question slightly to specify that I'm looking for a way to accomplish this without waiting for a feature request :) I'll certainly do that though if it turns out there's no existing way.

Comment: Is it really a good idea to store millions of objects on GCS? It feels to me that you need a point access on your BQ table and looking for an faster alternative. Maybe Cloud SQL or Cloud DataStore work for you in this case.

Comment: We're using bigquery to perform calculations on large datasets, but the results themselves will be reasonably sized. The number of objects representing the results will only get into the thousands.

Comment: Why do you want to do this i.e what's the use case?

Comment: Essentially we want results of our calculations to be available to a client program, and they're really only useful in these "partition chunks". I indicated I can and will write a script to do this manually if necessary, but it would be much cheaper and more efficient if we could just export the table like I'm describing.

Comment: Currently we're doing this by exporting the whole table to a relational database. Each "chunk" is several hundred rows, so for a relational database that's actually a pretty painful amount of data (thousands of chunks, hundreds of rows each). But these chunks are also completely static once they've been computed, so we think they're a perfect candidate for object storage (each chunk of rows is independently useful, and they're very static).

Comment: And I'm obfuscating the real exact nature of the data on purpose (it's for a proprietary tool), so I can see how my throwaway example of `client_id` and `attribute_id` doesn't seem very compelling. Just trust me hahaha

Comment: The [beta bigquery storage api](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery_storage/index.html) might give me basically what I'm looking for. Once I get a chance to test it we'll see!

Comment: The BigQuery Storage API uses rpc to provide an efficient way to access the data. It doesn't seem to be what you are looking for. I think that you have to either implement the script or wait for the feature request