# How to choose asynchronous or synchronous method variants in python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Let's assume I have a class that is used to perform I/O operations:

```
class CommunicationStack:
    def __init__(self, socket):
        self.socket = socket

    def sync_get_data(self):
        ...

    def sync_send_data(self):
        ...

    async def async_get_data(self):
        ...

    async def async_send_data(self):
        ...
```

As you can see it has sync and async variant for the same operations but it would be slightly inconvenient to write `async_get_data` or `sync_get_data` manually. I am looking for a smart way to have the same interface like

```
def get_data(self):
    ...  # call sync variant or return an awaitable, depending on caller type

def send_data(self):
    ...  # call sync variant or return an awaitable, depending on caller type
```

so it can be conveniently used like:

```
stack = CommunicationStack(...)

def thread_procedure():
    data = stack.get_data()  # get_data returns data

async def task_procedure():
    data = await stack.get_data()  # get_data returns an awaitable
```

I believe it can be done in some tricky way with inspections or some [black magic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1ndXuw7S0s&feature=youtu.be&t=2020):

```
def is_caller_coroutine():
    return sys._getframe(2).f_code.co_flags & 0x380
```

to check if caller is a coroutine or a function but it seems like a bad design to mess with python's guts.

---

The question is: what is a good way to choose appropriate variant? Or is there a better way to design everything like using [adapters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) or developing two independent `AsyncCommunicationStack` and `SyncCommunicationStack` classes?

Comment: David Beazley uses a more complete version of his **black magic** in `curio`'s `meta.py`: [see `from_coroutine()` here](https://github.com/dabeaz/curio/blob/e2c6ee29d1e988a216e4b76f9d3e3709f8738a36/curio/meta.py#L54)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to call async functions same way as regular ones, you may be interested in using [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html#example).

`asyncio` wants you to explicitly mark functions as `async` and to explicitly use `await` everywhere async stuff happens. In other words `asyncio` wants you to have different interfaces for sync and async code.

This is [intentional decision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19471967/1113207) made to fight with concurrency problems which is much harder to achieve when async nature of a code is hidden (like in gevent).

So yes - two different independent `AsyncCommunicationStack` and `CommunicationStack` classes is a way to go if you want to support both worlds. Although once you have async version you can cast write critical code with it and make it sync just running it with [asyncio.run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run). Problem only is that you won't be able to return to async world after that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I decided to write separate classes for async and sync communication. Dealing with two different *worlds* in one class would be a mess.