# Return log messages from async coroutine through a native generator

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

Assume we have some given framework, which let's us implement code in a generator:

```
def main_generator(input):
    # OUR ASYNC CODE HERE
    for index in range(5):
        # OR HERE
        yield message
```

Now, within the `main_generator` we would like to do some computations or io tasks and have some logging preferably by using the `logging` package with a custom stream handler.

How can I run async code from within that generator that yields a message to the framework whenever we log something?

**EDIT**: I tried to keep it general above, but let's be more specific:

I am using Flask to return streamed contents (see https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/streaming/) using a generator.
I want to stream the log messages that originate from the (potentially long running) code that is executed in the generator and thought async might be a good fit. I wanted to have one co-routine that does the work and one that reads the log messages from a list/queue and somehow transfers them to make the generator yield. But maybe it's not a good idea. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You can't have normal `asyncio` call (`await`) inside sync function (defined with `def`). Please [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56525798/1113207) to see why and what alternatives you have.

Comment: @MikhailGerasimov: Sure, I would need to start an event loop somewhere, but then it should be possible right?

Comment: If the generator and the IO tasks it runs are under your control, you can convert those tasks to async and make the generator async using an `async def`. Then you'll be able to iterate over it using `async for` from a coroutine that runs in the event loop.

Comment: The main_generator that yields the log messages must remain sync and cannot be changed to async

Comment: @PhilippFischer you can run async function inside `main_generator` by `asyncnio.run(coro())`. But this `coro` then will be run synchronously (no other coros can be run concurrently). If you want to run `coro` asynchronously, you should define `main_generator` with `async def`. Or to put it another way: ony async function can asynchronously run another async function except single toppest level async function that is executed by main loop.

Comment: @PhilippFischer What part of your program _can_ become async, then - the caller of the generator or the stuff that is called inside the generator? Does the generator block (wait for IO or equivalent)? Asyncio generally assumes that the whole program will be async, but there are ways around it - however, to recommend them, we need to understand the exact restrictions, because they're not clear from the example you gave.

Comment: @PhilippFischer if you use Flask, you can't use `asyncio` since Flask is not asynchronous framework. You should either use `gevent` or threads or, if you want to use `asyncio` switch to async framework like `aiohttp`.